# Pylab: Why does script run from Canopy command prompt but not Window's Powershell?

Tags: python, command-line

[image]

When I try and run the Python script below in the Canopy 64-bit command prompt it works but when I try it on the standard Window's Powershell it gives me an ImportError (see image). I ran the files the same way. I cd to the correct directory then type python ex.py

I have noticed this occur for other scipy modules as well.

```
from pylab import *

t = arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = sin(2*pi*t)
plot(t, s)

xlabel('time (s)')

ylabel('voltage (mV)')

title('About as simple as it gets, folks')

grid(True)

savefig("test.png")

show()
```

Comment: Check `where python` in cmd vs `get-command python` in PowerShell. Are they the same Python installation?

Comment: They link to the same python installations. I had python on my computer prior to downloading Enthought Canopy. Both the canopy command line and powershell show the same four python.exe locations.

Comment: Test a script that prints `sys.executable`, `sys.argv`, and `sys.path`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what I'm looking for. When I run the script the canopy command line creates a longer list, so it seems to me that the windows powershell is not accessing the directories it needs to to run scipy (numpy, matplotlib, ...) functions. Is it just a matter of inserting [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Python27", "User") into windows powershell for various paths in the canopy folder?

Comment: Do `echo %PYTHONPATH%` in the Canopy command prompt.

Comment: The `PATH` environment variable is used by the OS to find programs and libraries. That's unrelated to Python imports, which use the interpreter's `sys.path`. The `PYTHONPATH` environment variable is one way to extend `sys.path`.